# VBA / MS ACCESS Checking whether a given value appears in a table column

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'd like to check if values in range 1 to 20 are in column. My table looks like below:

```
ID      |     Value

1              34       
2              22       
3              56       
7              72       
15             88       
20             49
```

My code looks like this:

```
Dim a As Variant
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table", dbOpenSnapshot)
For a = 1 To 41
    If rs!ID <> a Then
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next a
TextBox = x
```

Unfortunately, this compairs only values with first value in column.
I want to count how many values from 1 to 20 are not in the ID column.
How can I loop compairing every record in that column?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DCount`, I guess:

```
x = DCount("*", "Table", "ID Between 1 And 41")
```